# Do Google Chrome extensions have access to draw on a tab?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Would it be possible to draw text on a tab using a Google Chrome extension?

Example:

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Generally extensions can't alter Chrome's chrome. The main exception is browser actions, but in that case it's fairly clear that that specific surface area is reserved for extension browser actions.